# Finding groups by the cycle decomposition of it's elements

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

I'm trying to find all finite intransitive permutation 2-groups $G$ with the following property:
all of their elements in their disjoint cycle decompositions have cycles of equal lengths, i.e. if $g\in G$ and $g=l_1 l_2 \cdots l_s$, then $|l_1|=|l_2|=\cdots=|l_s|=l$. Obviously, elementary abelian 2-groups are examples. Can we prove that only elementary abelian 2-groups and cyclic 2-groups have this property?

Edition: As Professor Derek Holt said cyclic groups are other examples.

Comment: Why do you say "obviously elementary abelian 2-groups are examples"? Which permutation representation are you thinking of? Are you counting cycles of length 1? Doesn't the cyclic group of ordfer 4 generated by $(1,2,3,4)(5,6,7,8)$ have this property? It is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed cyclic groups. An intransitive representation of p-groups is given in Example 2.2 of the paper "M. Alaeiyan and H. A. Tavallaee, permutation groups with the same movement, Carpathian. J. Math., 25(2), (2009), 147-156".

Comment: For any group you can just take two or more copies of the regular representation and it will have this property.